# Html,css: double border on table's rows

Tags: html, css

I am trying to "copy" http://grooveshark.com/#!/album/Halo+LP/5904939 this table right here.
This is my attempt http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/25/
Problem with my code is that somehow, when you hover over `<tr>`s  and the bottom border is double (2px up from 1)
I tried adding `border-collapse: collapse;` in my code and didn't fix it as a stack overflow post suggested.
Maybe i am doing it wrong.
Can someone try and make this work ? 
I have put all the important .css rows on the top 63 lines.

Note: I am using DataTables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grooveshark does not use a table layout, they have a `<div>` for each row with `-1px` top margin, so on hover it will overlap the row above.

You can use however the `element+element` **adjacent sibling selector** to achieve the same thing. First, only use top borders and on hover, with the element+element selector, change the border color of the next row:

```
table.dataTable tbody tr td{
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

table.dataTable tbody tr:hover td {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(192, 220, 255);
}

table.dataTable tbody tr:hover + tr td {
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(192, 220, 255);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/26/

Comment: wow, thank you very much for the solution, do you know how could i possibly add a border to the last item on my table ?

Comment: `table.dataTable tfoot tr td{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}`  this does not work

Comment: Try the `table.dataTable tbody tr:last-child td` selector, and also change the border color on hover too: `table.dataTable tbody tr:last-child:hover td`

Comment: i am trying to figure out the second way now , with the divs, my divs for the rows are `table.dataTable.hover tbody tr.odd` `table.dataTable.hover tbody tr.even` , i will try add a top margin -1 there , and i guess the border will have to go to the div as well

Comment: it doesnt add any border on those divs

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d1zqsayh/28/ , i am so close to doing it with divs , check the first 17 rows . am i close ? do you see what i am missing ?

Comment: They don't use a table, just simple <div> rows. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ozc1Le96/